# SharpCap LivePcapDevice not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, winpcap

So I have the reference to the dll files in there (PacketDotNet.dll and SharpCap.dll) and for some reason it cannot find these two classes.

```
private LivePcapDevice m_Device = null;

private IStatusUpdate m_IStatusUpdate;
```

Not sure what to do, if someone has experience with this issue, that would be helpful, but here is my setup, looks like it should be working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    

using System.Net;    
using System.Net.Sockets;    
using System.Threading;    
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;   

using System.Windows.Forms;    
using SharpPcap;    
using PacketDotNet;    
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;   
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;



namespace DHCP4IPTV    
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dealing with this problem about 30 minutes ago.
the solution is simple - use a lower version of SharpPcap.dll, I first used 4.2, but now I am using 3.3, and it is working fine.

[Here Are all SharpPcap versions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/files/SharpPcap/)